# How to test the source code for my own kbhit() alternative?

Tags: c, posix

I came across this code which was supposed to create an alternative POSIX function (`new_kbhit()`) for a DOS function `kbhit()`.

```
// Standard C  headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// POSIX system headers
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stropts.h>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FUNCTION:    kbhit_new()
//
// It returns 0. But if a key is pressed it returns number
// of pending bytes.
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int new_kbhit() {

    // Stdin's file descriptor (fd) is always 0, stdout's is 1 and stderr's is 2.
    static const int stdin_fd = 0;

    // This is static because we only want to disable buffering when this function is 1st called.
    static bool initialized = false;

    // Define the terminal structure named term.
    struct termios term;

    // Define an integer that will store the number of pending bytes.
    int bytes_waiting;

    if (! initialized) {
        // Get parameter STDIN of the terminal and store it inside termios structure (term).
        tcgetattr(stdin_fd, &term);
        // A: Remove termios structure's (term) flag ICANON inside the local modes i.e. c_lflag.
        // B: Removing flag ICANON will dissable canonnical processing.
        // C: When there is no canonical processing
        term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
        // Set terminal's attributes immediately (TCSANOW). Attributes are applied from termios (term).
        tcsetattr(stdin_fd, TCSANOW, &term);
        // Assign a buffer NULL to stream stdin. This disables buffering on stdin so pressed key is shown.
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        initialized = true;
    }

    // A:  ioctl operates on the "streams devices" but it needs it's file descriptors (fd)..
    // B:  Linux is not 100% POSIX compliant. It supports more than POSIX defines.
    // C:  Linux supports "streams device" FIONREAD (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/)
    // C:  FIONREAD device stores an integer i.e. "pending number of bytes" in last argument of ioctl.
    ioctl(stdin_fd, FIONREAD, &bytes_waiting);
    return bytes_waiting;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// EXAMPLE:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("Press any key to terminate:\n");

    while (! new_kbhit()) {
        putchar('.');
        fflush(stdout);
        usleep(1000000);
    }

    printf("\nDone.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Using POSIX standard I somehow deciphered what this code does *(comments)*. But to me it does exactly the same if I comment out almost everything inside the function `new_kbdhit()` which then looks like this:

```
int new_kbhit() {
    int bytes_waiting;
    ioctl(stdin_fd, FIONREAD, &bytes_waiting);
    return bytes_waiting;
}
```

So I can't confirm that this code does anything at all. How could I test it to see it's true potential? I have hard time understanding it's value at all.

Comment: If the terminal is in canonical input mode, pressing random letters etc. generally won't be detected for reading until line input is completed (e.g. by pressing return), or some input is followed by pressing the EOF character (usually CTRL-D).

Comment: How can I show this by modifying my example?

Comment: To show the effect of canonical input mode, you could change the original version's `term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;` to `term.c_lflag |= ~CANON;` to force canonical mode on.

Comment: Isn't canonical mode on by default? So it should already be like that after I commented things out?

Comment: With your change, new_kbhit will return 0 until enter is hit -- hit any other key and the loop in main will not exit.

Comment: Is this is because if canonical processing off, terminal ignores the special characters line NL (Enter)?

Comment: Another fine example why it is bad to repeat the function's name in the header comment.

Comment: @IanAbbott It shall be `term.c_lflag |= CANON;` without the tilde.

Comment: Do some experiments, you have two operations, the reset of `CANON`, and the setting of the buffer. -- Try with a TTY (your shell), and with a file (via redirection). If you're adventurous, additionally with a pipe.